# Universal Analytics - Event Tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am having issues with events showing up in Google Analytics. Can someone please help!

I am looking to track the event when an  is used in Google Analytics.

I have the following UA code in the  section of all pages.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-16728174-1', 'sjgweb.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

And have added this code to track the event:

```
<p><a href="mailto:sjg@sjg.com" onClick="ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘email’, ‘click to email’, ‘sjg@sjg.com’);">Send An Inquiry Today</a></p>
```

Nothing is showing in events... What do i need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single, curly quotes that you are using will not work with GA. You will need to change them to straight quotes, like this:

```
onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'email', 'click to email', 'sjg@sjg.com');"
```

Comment: Trigger the event, and immediately check in your Real-Time reports. You won't see anything in Standard reports just yet as you will need to wait about 24 hours.

Comment: I just saw a single ' that wasn't updated and I checked your suggestion for real time and they are working. Thanks